# How to load an XML Document to display as specific input format

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am currently trying to load an XML document to a C# program so that I can send it as a soap request.

Here is the XML Document I am trying to reference. It has a potential infinite number of rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ROWSET>
  <ROW num="1">
     <USER_ID></USER_ID>
     <FIRST_NAME>John</FIRST_NAME>
     <MIDDLE_NAME></MIDDLE_NAME>
     <LAST_NAME>Doe</LAST_NAME>
     <EMPLOYEE_NO>12345</EMPLOYEE_NO>
     <HOME_PHONE></HOME_PHONE>
     <EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>A</EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>
     <HIRE_DATE>05/17/2010</HIRE_DATE>
     <DEPARTMENT>Engineering</DEPARTMENT>
     <POSITION>Controls Engineer</POSITION>
     <SHIFT>N</SHIFT>
     <REPORTS_TO>Everhart,Robert</REPORTS_TO>
     <PAY_TYPE>H</PAY_TYPE>
     <EMPLOYEE_TYPE>R</EMPLOYEE_TYPE>
     <TERMINATION_DATE></TERMINATION_DATE>
     <PCN_CODE>Company_RV</PCN_CODE>

  </ROW>
  <ROW num="2">
     <USER_ID>RV12345</USER_ID>
     <FIRST_NAME>Jane</FIRST_NAME>
     <MIDDLE_NAME>G</MIDDLE_NAME>
     <LAST_NAME>Doe</LAST_NAME>
     <EMPLOYEE_NO>123455</EMPLOYEE_NO>
     <HOME_PHONE></HOME_PHONE>
     <EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>A</EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>
     <HIRE_DATE>09/15/2008</HIRE_DATE>
     <DEPARTMENT>Shipping</DEPARTMENT>
     <POSITION>Shipping Coordinator</POSITION>
     <SHIFT>2</SHIFT>
     <REPORTS_TO>Hajkova,Karin</REPORTS_TO>
     <PAY_TYPE>H</PAY_TYPE>
     <EMPLOYEE_TYPE>R</EMPLOYEE_TYPE>
     <TERMINATION_DATE></TERMINATION_DATE>
     <PCN_CODE>Company_RV</PCN_CODE>
```

I need to format this file into:

```
<ResultSet>
    <RowCount>1</RowCount>
    <Rows>
       <Row>
         <Columns>
           <Column>
             <Value>jdoe</Value>
             <Name>User_ID</Name>
           </Column>
           <Column>
             <Value>John</Value>
             <Name>FIRST_NAME</Name>
       and so forth
```

Once the xml file has been loaded and massaged into the correct format the variable containing the xml data would be placed into a soap envelope.

Comment: What have you tried to reformat this? And what errors did you encounter when you tried to do so?

Comment: I have not tried to reformat this as of yet. I am trying to determine what the best way to go about this is. This is my first web service project so everything is pretty new on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the xsd tool with the original XML in order to create classes to serialize the XML on memory.

Then use the XmlSerializer in order to get all into memmory:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(XmlClassTypeYouCreatedOnXsdTool);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xml);
var instance = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Use the same xsd tool with the output xml form you want to create in order to form another serializable classes.

Create functions to transform one object to another then send the object to your SOAP webreferences or use the same `XmlSerializer` and call `Serialize` to generate XML to your SOAP messages.

Comment: How do I specify that the schema to use a name/value pair? * full disclosure I am fairly green when it comes to C# and formatting xml.

Comment: In the simpler way, you would create a Class (`class ResultColumn` maybe?) with two properties: 'Name' and 'Value'. This is the simpler way. But again, manufacture a XML as example and run xsd custom tool and you should get your classes immediately! For using this tool, don't forget to run Visual Studio Command prompt, otherwise you will not find the `xsd.exe` tool.